# python for everyone L8 exercise

Tags: python

could you help me to figure out smth in one exercise that relates to **Lists** topic (Ch 8 - https://www.py4e.com/)?

here is my code:

```
def delete_head(t):
    del t[0]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
q = delete_head(letters)
print(q)
delete_head(letters)
print(letters)
```

I got this output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4gQu.png)

I cannot understand why output is not like ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']

Comment: Have a look at [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) for a better understanding of what the script does. You delete twice. Furthermore, your function does not return anything, so `print(q)` prints `None`.

Comment: Your function always deletes the first item in the list "t[0]". What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: I got it. I double deleted the head of the list. Thank you pals

Comment: Always you run this function, you're deleting the first character - _**in place**_ -  of whatever is `t` referencing to. It doesn't makes sense to assign the output to a variable once you didn't specified `return`. Even if you you do return `t`, you can see that `t is q` equals to  `True`. To explicitly make a copy to avoid such behavior, type: `t.copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
q = delete_head(letters)
```

This deletes 'a'

```
delete_head(letters)
```

and this deletes 'b' (since 'a' is already gone)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `delete_head()` twice, first in line 4 where you assign the return value of the function to q, and a second time in line 6.

Notice how q is None. This is because your function does not return the list. It get's a reference to the original list and deletes the first item. It does not return the list, but the changes aren't lost because you are using a reference to the original list. Therefore the return value of `delete_head()` is None